# Counter doesn t seem to add properly

Tags: python

When I was testing a counter, I discovered that it only seems to display the last item to go through it. For example, if something was excellent, it showed up as counted so it would be "1". However regardless of other data, the rest would be 0.

```
def mealrating(score, review):
    for x in range(0,len(score)):

        mp = 0
        mg = 0
        me = 0
        if score[x] >= 1 and score[x] <= 3:
            review.append("poor")
            mp = mp + 1

        if score[x] >= 4 and score[x] <= 6:
            review.append("good")
            mg = mg + 1

        if score[x] >= 7 and score[x] <= 10:
            review.append("excellent")
            me = me + 1

    print("The customer rated tonight's meal as:")
    print('Poor:' + str(mp))
    print('Good:' + str(mg))
    print('Excellent:' + str(me))
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting mp, mg, and me in each iteration.

```
def mealrating(score, review):
    mp = 0
    mg = 0
    me = 0

    for x in range(0,len(score)):
        if score[x] >= 1 and score[x] <= 3:
            review.append("poor")
            mp = mp + 1

        if score[x] >= 4 and score[x] <= 6:
            review.append("good")
            mg = mg + 1

        if score[x] >= 7 and score[x] <= 10:
            review.append("excellent")
            me = me + 1

    print("The customer rated tonight's meal as:")
    print('Poor:' + str(mp))
    print('Good:' + str(mg))
    print('Excellent:' + str(me))
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the counters outside the loop:

```
mp = 0
mg = 0
me = 0
for x in range(0, len(score)):
    # same as before
```

Otherwise they'll get reset at each iteration! To make your code more Pythonic, take the following tips into consideration:

- A condition of the form `x >= i and x <= j` can be written more concisely as `i <= x <= j`
- The idiomatic way to traverse a list is using iterators, without explicitly using indexes
- The conditions are mutually exclusive, so you should use `elif`
- Use `+=` for incrementing a variable

This is what I mean:

```
mp = mg = me = 0
for s in score:
    if 1 <= s <= 3:
        review.append("poor")
        mp += 1
    elif 4 <= s <= 6:
        # and so on
```